# Filling in polar flower plot as curves are being traced

Tags: matlab, octave, polar-coordinates

I'd like to animate a polar flower plot being drawn. I would hope for the result to look like this plot:
[image]

However the current result looks like this:
[image]

I've been rearranging the coordinates into multidimensional structs `x1` and `y1`, so it isn't just filling in as a plain cosine wave. Help is much appreciated.

```
clear;close all;
x = 0:0.01:pi*2;
r = cos(2*x).*sin(2*x);
figure
polar(x,r);
input('Press ENTER to start.');
hold on;
for x0 = x
  r0 = cos(2*x0).*sin(2*x0);
  polar(x0,r0,'o');
  x1 = [x0 2*pi 0];
  r1 = [r0 0 0];
  fill(x1,r1,'b');
  pause(0.033);
end
hold off;
```

Answer (score 3):

fill(..) takes cartesian coordinates, not polar ones.
So you must convert polar parameters into cartesian coordinates before calling fill(). Then, unless you need the polar frame, calling polar(..) is not required.

```
th = 0:0.01:pi*2;
r = cos(2*th) .* sin(2*th);
clf
x = r .* cos(th);
y = r .* sin(th);
c = fill(x,y,'b');
axis square tight
```

[image]